# How to use subprocess to fire and forget in python 2.7

Tags: python

I need to execute a command line in the bakground in python 2.7.  I need to fire and forget.

Here is the command:

```
cmd = "/usr/local/bin/fab -H %s aws_bootstrap initial_chef_run:%s,%s,%s -w" % (...)
```

How do I use the subproccess module?

e.g. is it

```
subprocess.call([cmd])

or 

subprocess.call(["/usr/local/bin/fab", "-H %s aws_bootstrap initial_chef_run:%s,%s,%s -w"])
```

I dont get how to use the list.  Or is every element of the list what would be a white space.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean ```subprocess.call(cmd)```? (without the square brackets)

Answer (score 2):

each thing that would be seperated by whitespace is a seperate entity of the list

`subprocess.call` is blocking however
`subprocess.popen` is non-blocking

```
cmd = ["/usr/local/bin/fab", "-H",var1,"aws_bootstrap initial_chef_run:%s,%s,%s"%(var2,var3,var4), "-w"]

subprocess.popen(cmd)  # dopnt wait just keep going
#or
subprocess.call(cmd)  # wait until the command returns
```

you may however alternatively pass the command as one big string

```
cmd = "/usr/local/bin/fab -H %s aws_bootstrap initial_chef_run:%s,%s,%s -w" % (...)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

in general this method(passing a single string) is frowned upon for some reason that has never been explained sufficiently to me

Comment: Without also passing `shell=True`, `subprocess.call(cmd)` where cmd is a string only works on Windows. On *all* systems, you want to avoid using shell=True whenever possible because it spawns an extra unnecessary process, and it comes with a whole lot of security concerns (especially if any part of `cmd` comes from user input or some other untrusted source).

Answer (score 0):

I used this recently to fire a perl script, like so:

```
    var = "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
    retcode = subprocess.call(["perl", '.\hgncDL.pl',var])
```

Comment: you need to pass the complete path to perl ... it is not aware of your environment unless you provide it

Comment: you would also need to escape the backslashes in the path or use raw strings

Comment: Works fine for me as is, but I appreciate the advice on my advice.

Answer (score 0):

## Working code

Define `hParam` and `runParams` in following code and you're good to go:

```
hParam = 'hParam'
runParams = (a,b,c)
args = ('/usr/local/bin/fab', '-H', hParam, 'aws_bootstrap', 'initial_chef_run:%s,%s,%s' % runParams, '-w')
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

## Details

1. How do I use `<any python module>` module?

   https://docs.python.org is a good starting point.
   In particular, docs for `subprocess` module available [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

   *I can't provide direct links for each case later in this answer due to restriction imposed by low reputation. Each time I will be referring to 'docs', look for a section in docs on the module.*
2. I need to execute a command line in the background in python 2.7. I need to fire and forget

   Consider `subprocess.Popen(args)`. Note capital 'P'.
   See docs for more details.

   `subprocess.call(args)` works in similar way, but it would block until the command completes. As stated in docs:

   > Run the command described by args. **Wait for command to complete**, then return the returncode attribute.
3. How to use the sequence form of `args` parameter?

   This is covered in "Frequently used arguments" section of docs:

   > args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names).

   Also, passing an `args` in a string form has its limitation:

   > If passing a single string, either shell must be True or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.

   Despite mentioned limitation, `subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe /?')` works for me. Win7, Python 2.7.8 64bit.

HTH, cheers.